# Internal error (-5002) occurred [الرسالة 131-183] sap b1 while adding Inventory transfer through DIAPI sap b1

Tags: vb.net, sapb1

```
Try
    Dim oST As SAPbobsCOM.StockTransfer = Nothing
    Dim tmpDt2 As New Date
    Dim cleanedDateString As String
    Dim formattedDate As String
    Dim DCDate As New Date
    oST = __bobCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oStockTransfer)

    oST.FromWarehouse = oForm.Items.Item("U_FromWH").Specific.Value & ""
    oST.ToWarehouse = oForm.Items.Item("U_ToWH").Specific.Value & ""
    tmpDt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(U_DocDate, GetDateFormat, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    'Dim DocDate As SAPbouiCOM.EditText = oForm.Items.Item("U_DocDate").Specific
    'tmpDt2 = DocDate.String

    'tmpDt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(U_DocDate, GetDateFormat, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    'cleanedDateString = DateString.Replace("#", "")

    'DateTime.TryParse(cleanedDateString, DCDate)

    'formattedDate = cleanedDateString
    'DateTime.TryParseExact(formattedDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", "", DateTimeStyles.None, DCDate)
    'formattedDate = DCDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    '' Dim DCDate As New Date
    ''DateTime.TryParseExact(tmpDt2, "yyyyMMdd", "", DateTimeStyles.None, DCDate)

    formattedDate = tmpDt2.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dim serqry As String = ""
    If oForm.Items.Item("U_FromWH").Specific.Value.ToString().StartsWith("P") Then
        ''''serqry = "select U_PDflSer Ser from OADM"
        serqry = "SELECT U_Series FROM [@INVTSER] WHERE U_PostingPeriod = (SELECT Indicator FROM OFPR WHERE '" + tmpDt2 + "' BETWEEN F_RefDate AND T_RefDate) AND  U_Branch= '5'"  'U_Location
    Else
        ''''serqry = "select U_VDflSer Ser from OADM"
        serqry = "Select U_Series FROM [@INVTSER] WHERE U_PostingPeriod = (Select Indicator FROM OFPR WHERE '" + formattedDate + "' BETWEEN F_RefDate AND T_RefDate) AND U_Branch= '3'"  'U_Location = '2'"
    End If

    Dim oRSSer As SAPbobsCOM.Recordset
    oRSSer = __bobCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset)
    oRSSer.DoQuery(serqry)

    Try
        'oST.Series = CInt(oRSSer.Fields.Item("Ser").Value.ToString())
        oST.Series = CInt(oRSSer.Fields.Item("U_Series").Value.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    oST.DocDate = tmpDt2

    Try
        oST.Comments = "Based On QC Transfer DocEntry : " & oForm.Items.Item("DocNum").Specific.Value
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Dim SampQty As Double = 0.0
    For iRow As Integer = 1 To mBTQ1.RowCount
        If mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_ItemCode").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value & "" <> "" Then
            If iRow <> 1 Then
                oST.Lines.Add()
            End If

            oST.Lines.SetCurrentLine(iRow - 1)
            oST.Lines.ItemCode = mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_ItemCode").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value & ""
            oST.Lines.WarehouseCode = oForm.Items.Item("U_ToWH").Specific.Value & ""

            oST.Lines.Quantity = CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_Quantity").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value) '- CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_SampQty").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value)
            'If optSFG.Selected = True And (ComboValue = "Normal" Or ComboValue = "Retest") Then
            '    oST.Lines.Quantity = CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_Quantity").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value) - CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("SmpQtyKg").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value)
            'Else
            '    '//B VC NLAG 28JAN2014 added code to set Quantity if QC Type is Transfer
            '    'oST.Lines.Quantity = CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_Quantity").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value) - CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_SampQty").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value)
            '    If (ComboValue = "Transfer") Then
            '        '//reset values in sample qty
            '        mBTQ1.Columns.Item("SmpQtyKg").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value = "0"
            '        mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_SampQty").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value = "0"
            '        '//set quantity
            '        oST.Lines.Quantity = CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_Quantity").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value)
            '    Else
            '        oST.Lines.Quantity = CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_Quantity").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value) - CDbl(mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_SampQty").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value)
            '    End If
            '    '//E VC NLAG 28JAN2014 added code to set Quantity if QC Type is Transfer
            'End If

            oST.Lines.BatchNumbers.Add()
            oST.Lines.BatchNumbers.SetCurrentLine(0)
            oST.Lines.BatchNumbers.BatchNumber = mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_BatchNum").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value
            oST.Lines.BatchNumbers.Quantity = oST.Lines.Quantity

            'If ComboValue = "Transfer" Then
            '    '//Update ItemGroup while Tranfer
            '    Dim dbsrc As SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item("@OBTQ")
            '    Dim oRs As SAPbobsCOM.Recordset = __bobCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset)
            '    oRs.DoQuery("Select ItmsGrpCod From OITM where ItemCode = '" & oST.Lines.ItemCode & "'")
            '    If oRs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            '        dbsrc.SetValue("U_ItmGrp", dbsrc.Offset, oRs.Fields.Item(0).Value)
            '    End If

            'End If

        End If  '//If mBTQ1.Columns.Item("U_ItemCode").Cells.Item(iRow).Specific.Value & "" <> "" Then

    Next  '//For iRow As Integer = 1 To mBTQ1.RowCount

    Dim RetVal As Integer = 0
    Dim ErrorCode As Long = 0
    Dim ErrorMessage As String = ""
    'ErrorMessage = oST.GetAsXML()
    RetVal = oST.Add()
    If RetVal <> 0 Then
        __bobCompany.GetLastError(ErrorCode, ErrorMessage)
        __oApplication.MessageBox(ErrorCode & " " & ErrorMessage)
        oForm.Freeze(False)
        BubbleEvent = False
    End If  '//If RetVal <> 0 Then

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oST)
    oST = Nothing

Catch ex As Exception
```

getting error while using this code to add inventory transfer through DIAPI

Comment: Which line does the error happen on? Also, it would be easier to look at the code in the question if the commented-out code was removed.

Comment: Conventionally, an internal error usually means a defect in the component raising the error.  Have you tried working through the appropriate support channels (if any exist)?

Comment: You should only call _oST.Lines.BatchNumbers.Add()_ for the second and subsequent batch numbers (similar to adding a line item).